# LESS divides background definition

Tags: css, less

I write in my LESS code:

```
 background: transparent url("images/visalogo.png") no-repeat scroll center 6px / 63px 22px;
```

But LESS renders this string to:

```
background: transparent url("images/visalogo.png") no-repeat scroll center 0.0952381px 22px;
```

It seems like LESS divides 6px to 63px;

How to avoid this bug?

Comment: Have you tried to use `@slash: <backtick>"/"<backtick>; /* slash */ ` (substitute `<backtick>` with the backtick, which i cannot do in this comment due to its special meaning in markdown syntax) and `background: transparent url("images/visalogo.png") no-repeat scroll center 6px @slash 63px 22px;`?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `strict-math` setting on? I think that should solve the problem because it would then divide only values within parantheses. If it doesn't solve then use `~"6px / 63px"` in the `background` value and it should compile as is because Less would treat it as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for  Harry.
The solution ~"6px / 63px" helped me.